# Deleted a repository in github but it still shows up in android studio? how do i remove it?

Tags: android-studio, github

Initially, i have 2 repositories on git hub. I deleted one and kept the other. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Ba7.jpg

However, android studio still thinks i have both of them.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrlbx.jpg

How can i fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still  have all the repository remotes locally configured.

Try in the repo folder to see the remote repositories :

```
git remote -v
```

And delete the remote with :

```
git remote rm <remote-name>
```